# Header breaks when zooming in. How I can fix that?

Tags: css

I have a header which has two list items. When I zoom screen the text breaks. How can I fix that?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: it's a big piece of Css with a header component

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this right you want to stop text from wrapping.

in CSS3 you can use the style

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

one possibility is that you could create a class with this:

ref: [example on w3](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)

Comment: You need to provide more information and code to illustrate the problem